# componentWillReceiveProps is getting multiple times after the router use in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`componentWillReceiveProps` is being called multiple times after router use in React, which is updating the component incorrectly
while in case of same previous page on tab change is working fine.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.expanded !== undefined) {
            this.setState({
                expanded: Boolean(nextProps.expanded)
            });
        }

        const selectedItems = updateSelectedItems(nextProps.items);
        console.log("selectedItems: "+selectedItems);
        this.setState({
            items: cloneDeep(nextProps.items),
            selectedItems,
            tempItems: cloneDeep(nextProps.items)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please include a piece of code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Please include also the part of the code where you use the router. The version of the router is very important, so please add the package.json info as well.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate your problem. This is a requirement for SO questions. As I know, there's no such widely known. behaviour that would go without saying.